# Area of projected hyper-ellipsoid onto unit sphere.

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

I would like to compute the area of a high-dimensional hyper-ellipsoid that is projected (x/norm(x,2)) onto the unit hyper-sphere of the same dimensions. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Even a pointer to an approximate solution would be great. I know how to do this for 2d but am stuck with higher dimensions.

Comment: Which kind of projection : Orthogonal, oblique, central ? Is the sphere $S_2$  in $R^3$ ?

Comment: I edited the question to be a bit more precise.

Comment: Thus a central projection. You should treat the case $\mathbb{R^3}$ first

Comment: Take a look at (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1187285)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, the solution in that link uses a polar parametrization and  works for 3 dimensions. My problem is in 100s of dimensions though. Perhaps I can think along those lines and figure out a solution.

Comment: I have had a different idea that works in 3D: it is to consider the cone with vertex in 0 and tangent to the ellipsoid. I know there is an easy manner to get it (but just at the moment I cannot retrieve it...). Substituting the cone to the ellipsoid, you have the contour of the area (which is easier to manipulate through a certain parameterization). But in nD, something puzzles me: what to you consider as a "surface" in the ball in nD: you will have to deal with hypervolumes...

Comment: Are you looking for something that could be called a "generalized solid angle" under which a scene (here an ellipsoid) is seen from the origin ? Have you already met this concept of "solid angle" ?

Comment: I have heard of the concept of solid angle, but need to study it. Is there a particular source (book, paper etc.) for reading up on this apart from Googling?

Comment: Take a look for example at (http://drdrbill.com/downloads/optics/photometry/Solid_Angle.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, you have been very helpful.